# Spring JMS - Declarative Transaction Management Using Annotations

Tags: spring-transactions, spring-jms

I have some old code I need to refactor which has programmatic transaction management for JMS.

There's a scheduled service that synchronously reads all messages (using JMS) and processes them one at a time. I am using `JmsTransactionManager` for transactions. Can I use declarative transaction management using annotations to manage my transactions per message instead of managing them programmatically like so:

```
//code from scheduled service's run method
private void run()
{
    javax.jms.Message jmsMessage = null;
    do
    {
        TransactionStatus status = null;
        try
        {
            status = jmsTransactionManager.getTransaction(new DefaultTransactionDefinition());
            jmsMessage = jmsTemplate.receive(heldTransmissionDestination);
            if(jmsMessage != null)
            {

                process(jmsMessage);
                jmsMessage.acknowledge(); //session is still open within the transaction
            }
            jmsTransactionManager.commit(status);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Exception: ", e);
            if(status != null)
            {
                jmsTransactionManager.rollback(status);
                logger.info("JMSTransaction rollback successful");
            }
            //since an exception occured, break out of the do-while
            break;
        }
    }
    while(jmsMessage != null);
}
```

Note that this code works. The configuration for the jmsTemplate has sessionTrasacted set to true, like below:

```
// from config
@Bean
public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
    JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
    jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
    // ... other stuff ommited for brevity
    return jmsTemplate;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it and it does work with annotations. However, a few caveats:

First, is the use of the `@EnableTransactionManagement` in your configuration (if you are using pure java DSL) like so:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JmsConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate() {
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate();
        jmsTemplate.setSessionTransacted(true);
        // ... other stuff ommited for brevity
        return jmsTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
        JmsTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager = new JmsTransactionManager();
        jmsTransactionManager.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory());
        return jmsTransactionManager;
    }

    //other bean definitions omitted for brevity
}
```

Alternatively you could do something like this in your XML configuration instead of the above:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jmsTransactionManager"/>
<bean id="jmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.JmsTransactionManager">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <ref bean="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Second, is the way transactions are [proxied](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-decl-explained) (AOP). Because of this, the logic that needs to be within a transaction needed to be moved into another class so that it can be proxied. Note that spring does detect your transaction manager automatically if you name it just transactionManager. But in my case, I have multiple such beans so I had to explicitly use this one; and refer to it in the value attribute of my annotations like so:

```
public class ServiceToSchedule
{

    @Autowired
    private JmsMessageProcessor jmsMessageProcessor;

    public void run()
    {
        Message jmsMessage = null;

        do
        {
            try {
                jmsMessage = jmsMessageProcessor.readAndProcessMessage();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                logger.debug("JMSException processing heldTransmission: ", e);
                break;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Exception processing heldTransmission: ", e);
                break;
            }

        }
        while(jmsMessage != null);
    }
}

public class JmsMessageProcessor
{

    @Transactional(value="jmsTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public Message readAndProcessMessage() throws JMSException
    {
        Message jmsMessage = jmsTemplate.receive(heldTransmissionDestination);
        if(jmsMessage != null)
        {
            process(jmsMessage);
        }
        //have to return to break out of the while in the caller
        return jmsMessage;
    }

    @Transactional(value="jmsTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.NESTED)
    protected void process(Message jmsMessage)
    {
        //code to process the jmsMessage, can potentially throw 
        //an exception that requires rolling back the jms transaction
    }   
}
```